# Inconsistent behaviour of ROL and OF

Tags: assembly, gdb, x86-64, intel

The manual states

> The OF flag is defined only for the 1-bit rotates; it is undefined in all other cases (except RCL and RCR instructions
>   only: a zero-bit rotate does nothing, that is affects no flags)

This is also shown in the pseudocode beneath

```
IF (COUNT & COUNTMASK) = 1
THEN OF ← MSB(DEST) XOR CF;
ELSE OF is undefined;
FI;
```

However, this is different when tried in practice.
Here is the code in question

```
mov rax, 0x4444444433332211
mov    cl, 0x44
rol    rax, cl
```

However the overflow flag seems to be set regardless,

[Before](http://prntscr.com/p0d0kw)

[After](http://prntscr.com/p0d1q4)

This behaviour isn't specific to 0x44 nor cl being the source, it will happen with any non-zero(provided there would be cause to set OF in the first place).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a flag is called "undefined", that means that its value is not updated in a defined way and thus *must not be used*.

It might actually change for some implementation-specific reason (in your case it was set), but you cannot make any assumptions that this is reliable or portable behavior.

Answer (score 1):

As Jan says, "undefined" can describe any behaviour, including leaving OF unmodified.  (To simplify partial-flag renaming).

> `IF (COUNT & COUNTMASK) = 1`

From the performance numbers, it's not clear if this is actually accurate documentation.

It might be that only the encoding with an *implicit* count of `1` actually sets OF in a data-dependent way.

According to Agner Fog's instruction tables, on Intel Sandybridge-family `rol r, 1` (short-form encoding) is 2 uops, while `rol r, imm` is 1 uop.

I think this is true even if the `imm8` immediate is encoded as `1` but I forget if I ever tested that.

But the `rol reg, cl` form is 2 uops, vs. 3 uops for variable-count shift instructions which have to leave FLAGS unmodified if the count is 0.  (The extra 2 uops are for conditionally merging into EFLAGS).

Comment: Related: [Why is the Overflow-Flag only set when single shifts are used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71771188) - some experiments on how OF is actually set for shifts by 2.